# Why does `soup.select_one` return a list?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm running below code

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
r = session.get(url, headers = headers)           
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content1 = soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents
temp = re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', content1)
```

then there is an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-feb1029c98d3> in <module>
     10 
     11 content1 = soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents
---> 12 temp = re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', content1)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    239 
    240     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 241     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    242 
    243 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

IMHO, this is because `content1` is a list, not a string as expected. It is weird to me that `soup.select_one` returns a list. In below example, it does not return a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

abc = """abcdd<div class="sense">xyz</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(abc, 'html.parser')
content1 = soup.select_one('.sense')

print(content1)
```

Could you please elaborate on this issue?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. You are already using an html parser, why are trying to parse the results with regex? regex and html are not friends.

Comment: @DeepSpace Your curiosity is so great. I intend to ask a question of how to use `BeautifulSoup` (without the loop) to achieve the same result obtained by `re`, but I encounter this error in preparing a code example. This is why I have to ask the question in this thread first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.select_one` does not return a list, it returns a single `tag` (as it promises).

```
content1 = soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling')
print(type(content1))
# <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

It is `content1.contents` which returns a list:

```
print(type(content1.contents))
# <class 'list'>
```

This list contains tags and elements that are contained in the `content1` tag.

If you want the HTML as a string you can use `str(content1)`:

```
print(re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', str(content1)))
```

outputs

```
['https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0071410.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/fr_bachelier.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/63854.mp3']
```

However, I'm a bit confused by your choice to use regex. You are already using a proper HTML parser. Generally speaking, using regex to parse HTML should be avoided as HTML is not a regular language, so using a regular expression to parse it might not always work as expected.

Comment: Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160020/how-to-use-beautifulsoup-to-get-the-same-result-obtained-by-regex)!