# How to use BeautifulSoup to get the same result obtained by regex?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all the values (which are links) of attribute `data-src-mp3` in the `content1` generated from the [url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer).

The link is contained in `<a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" title="Pronunciation for " data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3" data-lang="en_GB"></a>`.

One method is to use regrex `'data-src-mp3="(.*?)"'`

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
r = session.get(url, headers = headers)           
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content1 = soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents
output = re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', str(content1))

print(output)
```

the result is

```
['https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0071410.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/fr_bachelier.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/63854.mp3']
```

I would like to ask how to use `BeautifulSoup` and the structure `<a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" title="Pronunciation for " data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3" data-lang="en_GB"></a>` to obtain the same result without loop.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine selectors when using `.select`:

```
mp3s = [tag.attrs['data-src-mp3'] for tag in soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling [data-src-mp3]')]
```

or

```
mp3s = list(map(lambda tag: tag.attrs['data-src-mp3'],
                soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling [data-src-mp3]')))
```

`[data-src-mp3]` selects only elements that have the `data-src-mp3` attribute (with any value).

With a small change to have `'data-src-mp3'` in a single place:

```
mp3_tag = 'data-src-mp3'
mp3s = list(map(lambda tag: tag.attrs[mp3_tag],
                soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling [{}]'.format(mp3_tag))))
```

This solution might look more intimidating at first, but is much better than relying on the wrong tool (such as regex when parsing HTML).

Comment: This is so elegant :))))